# Alternative of nested for loops?

Tags: time-complexity, c++14

Is there any alternative to nested for loops, for eg. the code below contains 3 nested for loops which increases time complexity for the program. Any better way to get a similar result?

```
for(int i=1;i<=50;i++){
  for(int j=1;j<=50;j++){
    for(int k=1;k<=50;k++){
      cout<<i<<" "<<j<<" "<<k<<endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: C and C++ tags together should be used very rarely. Specify either one of them only.

Comment: Depends on the desired result. It's not a small detail.

Comment: Any similar result will produce the same 125,000 lines, unless you have a different definition of similar. So it's going to be 125,000 total repetitions, no matter what.

Comment: we can do alternative for any specific requirement but in current scenario you want to print only i, j, k value.

Comment: @Kandy can we the get the same result using recursion?

Comment: it also repeat same as in current scenario. If you want  any solution from us than you have to provide your purpose of three loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically for a dense array and where you need to access all elements, there isn't much that can be done.

For arrays with many zero elements, you might want to look into various sparse array formats (CRS, DLL etc).

The other thing that can be done is to analyze access patterns, depending on your task, you often don't need to access all elements. (E.g Matrix multiplication, where the system can often be described as a sparse DIA matrix)

When all else fails throw CPU's at it.

Comment: can recursion replace the nested for loop to get similar result?

Comment: I think it's safe to say that recursion is never going to be the answer to a performance problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem on OP is too broad. It required more details i.e what you want to achieve exactly.
It totally depends on what are you doing in 3 loops. To optimize you code to reduce execution time, you have to optimize your algorithm by understanding your goal.

Yes there are other methods which can replace loops like recursion etc... But it will not reduce execution time, but optimizing your algorithm should do.